# Link a member function directly to C method declared in a header

Tags: c++, winapi

Can I link a member function like this in some way?
redeclaring the method as a member and get it call the Mmsystem.h method to not have to wrap it?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>

  namespace SoundLib {

 public class CWave
 {
 public:
  // WaveIn call
  external UINT waveOutGetNumDevs(VOID);
 };

}
```

Comment: That code does not look much like C++ to me.

Comment: thank you, I'm expecting some help.

Comment: The following works on GCC/elf: `struct A { static void f() __attribute__((alias("f"))); }; extern "C" void f() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; } int main() { f(); A::f(); }` and prints "hello" two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to wrap it. Additionally, your code has some errors, such as `external` versus `extern` (though that was theoretical anyway) and `public` before your class.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really not a C++ programmer. I just playing with it. Anyway, using VS2008 it not complaims about public before the class name. But like you said its theoretical. I'm going to wrap it.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can wrap it with `inline` and even `static` and hope that compiler is smart enough (which it likely is).

```
class CWave {
public:
    static inline UINT waveOutGetNumDevs(void) { return ::waveOutGetNumDevs(); }
};
```

Comment: should be `{ return ::waveOutGetNumDevs(); }`

Answer (score 4):

You will need to explicitly call the function you wrapped:

```
class CWave
{
public:
    static UINT waveOutGetNumDevs(VOID)
    {
        return ::waveOutGetNumDevs();
    }
};
```

Note the double colon.  Since your method and the global function have the same name, you need the double colon to prevent infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no, you can't.